# Does changing the size of a matrix, but not the number of elements, preserve rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Specifically I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$ that I am reshaping (MATLAB) to a $\frac{n}{2} \times 2m $ matrix $A'$, where n is a multiple of 2.
Is the rank preserved? In limited testing in MATLAB it seems so, but I can't understand why. $\text{rank}\ A = m$, in my example if that matters.
Is this a change of Basis? I have seen [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9606/) but it only concerns removing rows, not also adding them as columns. Does $A'$ still span a subspace (or the same space?) of $A'$?

I don't have a very deep knowledge of linear algebra so an intuitive answer, if it exists, would be welcome.

Comment: It is not always true. Consider a $2 \times 2$ matrix with rank $2$. Under your reshaping, its size becomes $1 \times 4$ which can have a rank at most $1$.

Comment: Well, no. Otherwise you could apply it $n$ times to a $2^n\times m$ matrix and prove that every such matrix has rank at most $1$, which is nonsense.

Comment: @sudeep5221 ah yes, that makes perfect sense. The matrices I was working with had a special structure that allowed this property to hold, which I must have overlooked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah no this does not make sense at all. I was just looking at specific matrices that have this property and must've gotten confused..